# get particular value from a data using ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

```
attributes = query(View").first["description"]
```

`puts attribute`  prints following value

```
 "description" => "android.widget.ImageView{b10b2c28 V.ED..C. .....
I. 880,0-1760,672}
```

from this I have to get the value `880`

the same thing from the below value i have to print the value `1760.`

```
"description" => "android.widget.ImageView{b17b03c8 V.ED..C. ......
I. 1760,96-2832,576}
```

How it is possible in ruby

Comment: `\b\d+\b(?=,\d+-\d+)`

Comment: It would be better if you didn't have `......`, as readers will want to know if 880 and 1760 are necessarily the first integers in each string. If they are, `/\d+/` should be enough. If they are not necessarily the first integers in the string, other clues are needed. Are they always followed by something like `,12-345,678}`? Are they always preceded by `I. `? Please edit your question to clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like

```
/\d+(?=,\d+-\d+,\d+}$)/
```

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/lF3uQ2/1)

**TEST**

```
> print '"description" => "android.widget.ImageView{b10b2c28 V.ED..C. .....
  I. 880,0-1760,672}'.scan(/\d+(?=,\d+-\d+,\d+}$)/)[0]
=> "880"

> print '"description" => "android.widget.ImageView{b17b03c8 V.ED..C. ......
  I. 1760,96-2832,576}'.scan(/\d+(?=,\d+-\d+,\d+}$)/)[0]
=> "1760"
```

Comment: am getting `imageview_attributes.scan(/\d??+(?=,\d+-\??d+,\d+})/)
                               ^ (SyntaxError)`

Comment: can u please edit that in code.i dont know hoe to use with exact regex

Comment: i used this way  'imageview_attributes = query("imageView").first["description"]
 
  imageview_attributes = imageview_attributes.to_s
   
  imageview_attributes = imageview_attributes.scan(/\d­+(?=,\d+-\­d+,\d+})/)'

Comment: also is there any way to return as integer instead of ["880"]

Comment: @chinchu yup. Use can write `..scan(...)[0]` . I have edited in my answer

Comment: The OP may be asking for `to_i`.

Comment: @chinchu wrap the `scan` in `to_i` to convert to int